# ThreadLocal in RMI connection

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, game-engine, rmi

I wrote a Java game with some singleton classes. The specifications provide that several matches of this game can start on the same Server, so I used TheadLocal variables to instance Singleton classes in different thread. The problem is that when Server communicates with a Client it's like the Controller's thread change, so the instances of the ThreadLocal are resetted. Is this normal? What can I do?

Sorry for my bad english, thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should also provide some information about how does you server work (worker threads, using select()).

Comment: @MatejKormuth He's using RMI. That answers both those questions.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work. The RMI Specification makes no guarantees about any association between clients, or client threads, and server threads.

It seems to me that you are looking for the [Remote Session pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266658/207421).